# Share data between Unity Project to Android Studio java code

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I Export my unity project to the android studio using these steps:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-android-app.685240/

But I want to ask that is there any option that I can send data from my native android app Intent to unity scripts because I am making an online game and I need to transfer my tokens to unity.

I have saved the token in shared preferences using **[Encrypted SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data)** library in the android studio, server required token to respond on request so I want the token from my android intent to unity script.

Or Is there any way in  unity to decrypt this token.

Please help me I am stuck

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, your game is made in AndroidStudio, but you are trying to "plug" Unity? Instead of make the game in Unity and attach Android plugins?

Comment: @Lotan , Actually it's an online game, activities other than game are handled in android studio and game is handled by unity, I have also given the link how I exported the unity project to android.... the problem I am getting is, on server I need to send auth token that is in encrypted file, how can I get it from android or decrypt it in unity. I also have given the link of encryption docs. Thanks Still have doubts let me know thank u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My workaround will be to approach this problem as if you are using an android plugin for Unity.

So you can use any activity that inherits from `UnityPlayerActivity`, or create your own.

Then use the in-build method `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage`, passing as parameters the gameObjectName that will have the receiver script attached, the name of the receiver method inside the receiver script, and the data you want to handle, in your case, the token.
something like: `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(gameObjectName, "OnResultMethodName", tokenString);`

You can see an example of how to do that here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example

Comment: I am using unity project as library in my android studio project, is there any option for that ?

Comment: @PankajSharma Yes, It works the same, I've updated my answer attaching a link to an example using unity project as library.

Comment: @PankajSharma Remember to mark the answer as correct (if it is!)